# Extra (hidden) data in form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have been busy learning php / mysql.
To make sure I understand how and what I am doing, I have started a project to build my own php game.

I got to the point to create a registration form.
The form works as it is programmed.

In the form is a selection for 5 different classes, the idea is when a certain is selected the starting stats for that class gets placed in to the database.
Here is the class selector, yes I know it has the `die()` in, but that shows me it "works".

**My question is:**
How do I add the extra "hidden" input? (like hp, mana, def, >>>>)

I tried to replace the `die()` with:
`$query = " INSERT INTO user (hp,deff) VALUES (3,2)";`

```
    //Class selector
    if($_POST['class'] == 'ssd')
    {
        die("Selected ssd as Class.");
    }
    elseif($_POST['class'] == 'holo')
    {
        die("Selected holo as Class.");
    }
    elseif($_POST['class'] == 'cleric')
    {
        die("Selected clerric as Class.");
    }
    elseif($_POST['class'] == 'wizzard')
    {
        die("Selected wizz as Class.");
    }
    elseif($_POST['class'] == 'floppy')
    {
        die("Selected pitcher as Class.");
    }
    elseif(empty($_POST['class']))
    {
        die("Select a Class.");
    }
```

Full code:

```
<?php
require("common.php");

if(!empty($_POST))
{
// Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty username
    if(empty($_POST['username']))
    {
        die("Please enter a username.");
    }    
// Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty password
    if(empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        die("Please enter a password.");
    }
//Class selector
    if($_POST['class'] == 'ssd')
    {
        die("Selected ssd as Class.");
    }
    elseif($_POST['class'] == 'holo')
    {
        die("Selected holo as Class.");
    }
    elseif($_POST['class'] == 'cleric')
    {
        die("Selected clerric as Class.");
    }
    elseif($_POST['class'] == 'wizzard')
    {
        die("Selected wizz as Class.");
    }
    elseif($_POST['class'] == 'floppy')
    {
        die("Selected pitcher as Class.");
    }
    elseif(empty($_POST['class']))
    {
        die("Select a Class.");
    }
//Character name
    if(empty($_POST['charname']))
    {
        die("Please enter a Charactername.");
    }    
// Make sure the user entered a valid E-Mail address
    if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        die("Invalid E-Mail Address");
    }


//SQL query to see whether the username entered by the user is already in use
    $query = "
            SELECT
                1
            FROM user
            WHERE
                username = :username
        ";

    $query_params = array(
            ':username' => $_POST['username']
    );

    try
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die("Failed to run query:");
    }
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if($row)
    {
        die("This username is already in use");
    }    
// email address unique check
    $query = "
            SELECT
                1
            FROM user
            WHERE
                email = :email
        ";

    $query_params = array(
            ':email' => $_POST['email']
    );

    try
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die("Failed to run query");
    }

    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    if($row)
    {
        die("This email address is already registered");
    }

//charname unique check 
    $query = "
            SELECT
                1
            FROM user
            WHERE
                charname = :charname
        ";

    $query_params = array(
            ':charname' => $_POST['charname']
    );

    try
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die("Failed to run query");
    }

    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    if($row)
    {
        die("This charactername is already taken");
    }
    $query = "
            INSERT INTO user (
                username,
                charname,
                password,
                salt,
                email,
                class
            ) VALUES (
                :username,
                :charname,
                :password,
                :salt,
                :email,
                :class
            )
        ";

    $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647));

$password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt);

    for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++)
    {
        $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt);
    }

    $query_params = array(
            ':username' => $_POST['username'],
            ':password' => $password,
            ':salt' => $salt,
            ':email' => $_POST['email'],
            ':charname' => $_POST['charname'],
            ':class' => $_POST['class']
    );

    try
    {
        // Execute the query to create the user
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die("Failed to run query: ");
    }

    die("Redirecting to login.php");
}


?>
<h1>Register</h1>
<b>NOTE! A admin or moderator will NEVER ask you for a loginname or password. Only a Character is needed for help or problems.</b>
<form action="register.php" method="post"> 
    <br />Loginname<b> keep this private!</b>:<br />
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" /><br />
    Charactername<b> Advice is to use different name then the loginname, this is how people will see you</b>: <br />
    <input type="text" name="charname" value="" /><br />
    E-Mail: <br />
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" /><br />
    Password: <br />
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />
    Class: <br />
    <input type="radio" name="class" value="ssd"> Solid State Defender<br />
    <input type="radio" name="class" value="holo"> Hologram<br />
    <input type="radio" name="class" value="cleric"> Office Cleric<br />
    <input type="radio" name="class" value="wizzard"> IT Wizzard<br />
    <input type="radio" name="class" value="floppy"> Floppy Picher<br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Register" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Are you looking for the <input type="hidden" .../> field?

Comment: Which `die` are you getting? What happens when you put that query in that conditional?

Answer (score 0):

Create two more tables:

`Classes` -> This table should have a `ClassId`, `ClassName`, and `Starting Class Properties` (ie: HP, Mana, etc).

`UserProperties` -> This table should have columns that contain a reference to each user, a `PropertyName` and `PropertyValue`

When a new user is created, load up the selected class from the `Classes` table and populate the `UserProperties` table with the selected class' initial properties.

Now when you can query and update specific properties for specific users.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any hidden input fields, as those fields are presumably predefined for each class.This means you could store them on a seperate table(`Classes(classID, classLabel, HPInitial, ManaInitial))` for example) in your database.

Then in your query, you could simply add:

```
$query = ' INSERT INTO user (...,mana, hp,...) VALUES 
              (...,
                  (SELECT ManaInitial FROM Classes WHERE classLabel = :class),
                  (SELECT HPInitial FROM Classes WHERE classLabel = :class),
              ...);
```

*This approach would cause a lot of problems if you add more attributes to the class as you will have a lot of subqueries. A more practical approach would be to select the attributes beforehand and add them to the insert query before executing it.*

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting solutions, I like yours axlj

I actually kept messing around, and found a solution, tell me what you think of it.
Still thinking to place the basic stats in a table, but I am happy this actually works.

```
//Class selector and full userinfo prepare

if($_POST['class'] == 'ssd')
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO user (username,charname,password,salt,regkey,email,class,hp,mana,atkpwr,defpwr,speed,crit,luck) VALUES (:username,:charname,:password,:salt,:regkey,:email,:class,'4','0','3','3','1','1','5')";
}
elseif($_POST['class'] == 'holo')
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO user (username,charname,password,salt,regkey,email,class,hp,mana,atkpwr,defpwr,speed,crit,luck) VALUES (:username,:charname,:password,:salt,:regkey,:email,:class,'4','2','5','0','1','1','5')";
}
elseif($_POST['class'] == 'cleric')
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO user (username,charname,password,salt,regkey,email,class,hp,mana,atkpwr,defpwr,speed,crit,luck) VALUES (:username,:charname,:password,:salt,:regkey,:email,:class,'4','3','2','1','1','1','5')";
}
elseif($_POST['class'] == 'wizzard')
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO user (username,charname,password,salt,regkey,email,class,hp,mana,atkpwr,defpwr,speed,crit,luck) VALUES (:username,:charname,:password,:salt,:regkey,:email,:class,'3','3','5','1','1','1','5')";
}
elseif($_POST['class'] == 'floppy')
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO user (username,charname,password,salt,regkey,email,class,hp,mana,atkpwr,defpwr,speed,crit,luck) VALUES (:username,:charname,:password,:salt,:regkey,:email,:class,'2','1','3','2','1','1','10')";
}
elseif(empty($_POST['class']))
{
    die("Chose a class plix.");
}
```